# RADStudio IOS deployment problems

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe6

I am trying to build an iOS app using RadStudio XE6 and have nothing but problems trying to get the app on to iTunes connect.  These are the steps I have carried out so far:-

1. Have created an app id in developer portal making note of the ID used.
2. Have created and downloaded a provisioning profile for the app with my iPhone registered as one of the devices.
3. I have created the App in iTunes connect
4. I have gone into the Project Options in RadStudio and change the provisioning so the certificate is the certificate I have created and the Mobile Provision profile is the one I have downloaded from the developer portal for this app I created in stage 1.
5. I hit project deploy and the app compiles, links and builds an IPA file on my Mac.
6. I then try and use application loader to send the IPA file through to iTunes connect. I get the following errors:

   > **ERROR ITMS-9000:** Your bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value xxxxxx. If you want to change your bundle identifier you will have to create a new application in iTunes connect
   >
   > **ERROR ITMS-9000:** This bundle is invalid. The application identifier element is missing. It should contain your 10-character Apple developer id, followed by a dot followed by your identifier.
   >
   > **ERROR ITMS-9000:** Inavlid launch image - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later.

Anybody have a clue what is causing these problems and more importantly how I fix them?

---

**UPDATE - 15th September**

After following the instructions in the answer below and also the link contained within in I got a message from application loader that the file did not include a payload directory. So I changed the name of the file to a zip file and unzipped it to find the Payload folder.  And sure enough application loader error is now no .app bundles found in the package.

---

**UPDATE - 17th September**

I created a new Provisioning profile and tried to build and deploy the app with that, changing the budnle id in the version info accordingly.  Still the same message of No payload folder. So I then quickly created a new app in rad studio and attached the provisioning profile and bundle id in the version info and build and deployed that... After adding the images that worked.. So there is something in my existing project that is screwed. I just have to find out what...

Comment: What are the current values (written above as 'xxxxxx')? I have seen Android apps added to the store with default com.embarcadero.* IDs, because the developer forgot to change it to match their own company. By any chance could this be a similar issue that's being caught by iTunes Connect?

Comment: Good question but I simply changed those to hide the client URL. It shows the correct URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Project|Options|Version Info** set:

- **CFBundleIdentifier** to your app unique ID (like com.yourdomain.yourappname). It must match what you set up in the Apple provisioning information.
- **CFBundleDisplayName** to the name you want to appear below your icon on the IOS device.
- **CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion** to *7.1* (you should compile against the IOS 7.1 SDK).
- **CFBundleVersion** to match the version number you have set in the Apple store information.

You can read more about deployment [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Submission_to_the_App_Store). You can read more about provisioning [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Provisioning_an_iOS_Application). You can read more about what NOT to do [here](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/2303).

Finally, [this developer](https://pjstrnad.com/submitting-application-apple-store-delphi/) seems to have had the same errors as you and tells how he fixed it.

Comment: Did all of the above and got exactly the same error messages. Will check out the link you sent.

Comment: Progress of sorts.. I now get ERROR ITMS-9000:"The IPA is invalid. It does not include a payload directory". Which I have yet to research...

Comment: This is possibly the single most frustrating thing.  So I have an app ready to go to the store and no matter what I do it will not upload to iTunes connect.  Perhaps I should have just done it in Xcode and Objective C... I am still stuck on the above error - Does not include a payload directory

Comment: An IPA file is just a zip archive. Open up someone elses and check out the structure. Open up yours and see how it is different? Can you load it on the device with debug mode?

Comment: I don't actually have an IPA to compare with but when I change the IPA to a zip file and open it up it contains a Payload folder with the app inside.  Plus when it is a zip file it gets a different message in the APP Loader than when it is an IPA file.  I am concluding that the messages I am receiving from the App Loader are throwing me off the scent somewhat.

Comment: I can't get my XE7 IPA to submit either but I have the infamous "ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'myAppName' for executable 'Payload/myAppName.app/myAppName'. " message. The XE6 one submitted fine.

Comment: I solved my issue today by using the auto provisioning downloader built into the Xcode account area. Some info about using it here: http://blog.smallsharptools.com/post/81948584244/how-to-provision-ios-apps-with-xcode-5-1

Comment: Now have it working. I had mixed up the advice in the blog with your answer and the Plist in the deployment was left unticked and therefore was not being packaged.  Once I put it back on it uploaded fine.